# How to get Unicode of smiley in scala

Tags: java, scala, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I am getting smilies as an input from the user.

```
val emojis=""
```

I want its unicode to store in DataBase.
in my console it is printing like this

may be question is unclear
i want like this  to  `\u263a;`

Comment: *"I want its unicode to store in DataBase"* I don't quite understand. You *have* the Unicode -- the string. JVM strings are UTF-16 (each "character" is a UTF-16 code point). These particular emojis require two code points per character: `"\uD83D\uDE03"` ([U+1F603](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F603)), `"\uD83D\uDE1C"` ([U+1F61C](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F61C)), and `"\uD83D\uDE0D"` ([U+1F60D](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F60D)). As Jon says, just make sure that you're storing and retrieving what you're given faithfully.

Comment: can i know how you are getting unicode from the input emoji?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for [U+263A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm). The best way to represent this in *source code* is with a Unicode escape sequence:

```
val smiley = "\u263a";
```

You *then* need to check that:

- Your database is able to store it (check the type of your field, potentially collation, potentially database connection settings)
- You can retrieve it correctly from the database
- Whatever you want to display it on is able to support it (check the font, aside from anything else)

Given the number of ways in which it can go wrong, it's important to work out exactly *where* any problems are - which usually involves checking the UTF-16 code unit within the string you're trying to display, rather than just going straight for "does it display properly".

Comment: Actually I think those emojis are up in the area where you get into surrogate pairs: `"\uD83D\uDE03"`, `"\uD83D\uDE1C"`, and `"\uD83D\uDE0D"` respectively in Java's UTF-16 strings. That's what I get when I paste them into my "Unicode Show Me" bin: http://jsbin.com/erajer/16 (it really should be called a "UTF-16 Show Me"), and if I paste that into a Java program as `System.out.println("\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE1C\uD83D\uDE0D");` (I don't do Scala), I see the emojis on the console.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It depends on which character you want. U+263A is within the BMP, so it's not too bad. I have a similar "program" at http://tinyurl.com/unicode-explorer by the way - go to the bottom of the page. It's about the only Javascript I've written in the last 10 years!

Comment: When I use your tool for the three characters in the question, I get [U+1F603](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F603), [U+1F61C](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F61C), and [U+1F60D](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F60D) -- which matches what I got when I finally decoded the UTF-16 my (inferior!) tool gave me. [U+263A](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=263A) is a different character from the three in the question.

Comment: None of which really changes the answer: Store what you're given, being certain that you're doing it faithfully and correctly transforming at each step along the way if necessary. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: ah - the characters in the queation weren't rendering at all for me, so I suspected they were broken. My bad!

Comment: Oh, interesting! Linux rules! ;-) (But to be fair to M$, they show correctly for me on IE11 on Win8, too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet means i have to force user to send in this format(`\u263a`), and save as it is

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti: No, that's not what this means.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was inspired by you to improve my tool: http://tinyurl.com/unicode-show-me (by copying several functions from yours whole-hog, please let me know if that or crediting you on it are at all a problem and I'll sort it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: No problem at all. You may well have managed to improve the JS as you went along. I'm very clearly not a JS coder :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: :-) And I'm nothing like the C# guy you are. It was absolutely fine, other than falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) with `i` in `displayData` (sorry, I meant to mention).

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution i have to escape java

```
 val unicode=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(emojis)
```

and when i am getting back from the  database i need to unescape Java